# Exporting Chart Not Keeping Navigator Series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are in the process of upgrading to HighStock 6.1 from HighStock 5. We allow users to show only one series on the stock charts (out of any number of possible series). When the user clicks on the series in the legend we hide all other series and show only the one clicked. We also change the `navigator.series` to be the selected series:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    turboThreshold: 0,
    connectNulls: false,
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: false
    },
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(event) {
        var currChart;
        var pnlChartExport;
        var pnlNoChartExport;
        var divNoChartExport = $('[id$=divNoExportSupp]');
        var thisSeries = this,
          chart = this.chart;
        if (this.visible === true) {
          this.hide();
          chart.get("highcharts-navigator-series").hide();
        } else {
          this.show();
          chart.series.forEach(function(el, inx) {
            if (el !== thisSeries) {
              el.hide();
            }
          });
          chart.get("highcharts-navigator-series").setData(thisSeries.options.data, false);
          chart.get("highcharts-navigator-series").show();
          chart.setTitle({
            text: thisSeries.options.name
          }, undefined, false);
          var points = [];
          var minVal = 0.000;
          thisSeries.options.data.forEach(function(theData) {
            points.push(theData.y);
          });
          minVal = Math.min.apply(Math, points);
          if (minVal >= 0) {
            chart.yAxis[0].update({
              min: 0
            });
          } else {
            chart.yAxis[0].update({
              min: undefined
            });
          }
          currChart = thisSeries.userOptions.chartLoc;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when we export the chart (via external button still calling `chart.exportChart`) we get the currently shown series and navigator series and append some other information (footer text, etc).

```
function chartExportLoc(chartid, exportType, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize) {

    if (!marginSize) {
        marginSize = 15;    //HighCharts default
    }

    var chart = $('#' + chartid).highcharts();

    if (chartid == "chartStock") {
        var navigatorData = chart.get("highcharts-navigator-series").options.data;
        var chartSeries = chart.userOptions.series;

        chart.exportChart(
            {   type: exportType, scale: 1 },
            {
                title: { text: unescape(encodeURI(graphHeader)), margin: marginSize },
                navigator: {series: {data: navigatorData} },
                legend: { y: -6 },
                subtitle: { y: 3, text: unescape(encodeURI(graphFooter)) },
                chart: { spacingBottom: 35, shadow: false, height: 1.1 * chart.chartHeight, width: 800 },
                series: chartSeries
        });
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Under HighStock 5 this worked fine. However, now it does not show the navigator series for any export except for the initially loaded series - the navigator window shows no points.

How can I maintain the same result under HighStock v6 with the navigator series = visible series upon export? Here is a live [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojdcx1r0/) with data and all options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, you don't need to define separate series in `navigator.series` for every series you define in your chart configuration object, because Highcharts will do it by itself, basing on `Series.showInNavigator` flag. The best and fastest way to do that correctly is by defining simple logic implementation, using `update` appropriate series on `legendItemClick` event. Then your export should work correctly. Please take a look at code and example below:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick(e) {
          e.target.chart.series.forEach(s => {
            if (s === e.target) {
              s.update({
                showInNavigator: true,
                visible: !s.visible
              })
            } else if (s.name.split(" ")[0] !== "Navigator") {
              s.hide()
              s.update({
                showInNavigator: false
              })
            }
            e.preventDefault()
          })

        }

      }

    }
  }
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/yf4stjmw/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.showInNavigator
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.visible

***[EDIT]***

All of your chart's series are hidden in exported files, in the reason of this lines of code:

```
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.series.forEach(function(el) {
        if (el.index !== 0) {
          el.hide();
        }
      });
      this.get("highcharts-navigator-series").show();
    }
  }
```

Don't forget that `load` event handler is also triggered when exporting, that's why you need to delete those lines of code. Then it should work as you wish.

Comment: This is closer. Now the export shows the navigator series - but not the main series. Take a look at my chartExportLoc func - in here we alter the chart title and other properties.

Comment: Because you need to delete the `series` and `navigator` definitions from the exporting configuration object which you passing as an argument to `exportChart()` function.

Comment: I have done that. See updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ojdcx1r0/27/

Comment: Issue is the `chart.events.load`. Removed that and chart behaves as expected on page and on export.

Comment: Yep, I added comment just as you answered. Thank you very much!